# 2 D char array in C where each value is a C string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int talk_db(MySQLConnection *sql_conn, MySQLQuery *sql_query)
{
    sql_query->ExecuteQuery();

    for(unsigned int i=1;i <= sql_query->GetResultRowCount(); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=1; j<=sql_query->GetFieldCount(); j++)
        {
            printf("%s\t", sql_query->getString(i,j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

O/P:

```
alice123    alice   2018-02-16 18:34:11 alice@apple.com 12343532    1234235354645   /home/roshan/thesis/server/data/user/alice  12343544        
bob432  bob 2018-02-15 18:34:11 bob@orange.com  8765433554356   7654332 /home/roshan/thesis/server/data/user/bob    5467456456      
charlie charlie 2018-02-16 10:34:11 c@c.com 4563465456  564574654   /home/roshan/thesis/server/data/user/charlie    567456745654356     
eve99   eve 2018-02-15 13:34:11 eve@yahoo.com   634563223432    23453475    /home/roshan/thesis/server/data/user/eve    435343241231111
```

These values are coming from database.

How I could declare and put these value in 2D char array so data[0][1] will give me alice.
Also I wanted to add a parameter to talk_db to fetch these value in a 2D array. I do not know in advance how many rows it will return.

Do I need a 3D array, how to declare that?

Comment: You are using C++ code. When it comes to lists, vectors, maps, etc. C and C++ solutions differ significantly. So do you want C or C++?

Comment: cpp just for cout, i want c

Comment: "*I do not know in advance how many rows it will return.*" what about the number of columns and the maximum strings' length?

Comment: Yes, I know about columns, but sql_query->GetResultRowCount() can also be used to get no of rows or not ?

Comment: Please tell the reason before downvoting the question.

Comment: A c-string is a (`0`-terminated) `char`-array. So if you want to have a 2D-array of "c-strings", you need a 3D-array of `char`, yes.

Comment: A 2D-array of `char*` might do as well.

Comment: Does your compiler support VLAs?

Comment: I'm using g++ Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04, I know it's g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: To do C you need to use gcc, using g++ you do C++.

Comment: Please find out whether you want to code in C or C++ and adjust the tags / code accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I use gcc now to compile the code. I need C based array solution.

Comment: If you want to use C, you can't use `cout`, you need to use `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C version of what you want needs to use `malloc` & friends.

```
char ***talk_db(MySQLConnection *sql_conn, MySQLQuery *sql_query, size_t *rows, size_t *cols)
{
    char ***results;

    sql_query->ExecuteQuery();

    *rows = sql_query->GetResultRowCount();
    *cols = sql_query->GetFieldCount();

    results = calloc(*rows, sizeof *results);

    if(results == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(size_t r = 0; r < *rows; ++r)
    {
        results[r] = calloc(cols, sizeof *results[r]);
        if(results[r] == NULL)
        {
            free_results(results, *rows, *cols);
            return NULL;
        }

        for(size_t c = 0; c < *cols; ++c)
        {
            // assuming it returns a char*
            char *res = sql_query->getString(r,c);
            if(res)
            {
                results[r][c] = strdup(res);
                if(results[r][c] == NULL)
                {
                    free_results(results, *rows, *cols);
                    return NULL;
                }
            } else
                results[r][c] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return results;
}

void free_results(char ***results, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    if(results == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
    {
        if(results[r] == NULL)
            continue;

        for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            free(results[r][c]);

        free(results[r]);
    }

    free(results);
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
size_t cols, rows;
char ***results = talk_db(sql_conn, sql_query, &rows, &cols);

if(results == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to get query\n");
    return; // or something else
}

// printing results:

for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
{
    for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
        printf("%-20s", results[r][c] ? results[r][c] : "NULL");
    puts("");
}

free_results(results, rows, cols);
```

When creating the copy of the cells, I do this:

```
            char *res = sql_query->getString(r,c);
            if(res)
            {
                results[r][c] = strdup(res);
                if(results[r][c] == NULL)
                {
                    free(results[r]);
                    results[r] = NULL;
                    free_results(results, *rows, *cols);
                    return NULL;
                }
            } else
                results[r][c] = NULL;
```

I haven't used the C interface of MySQL, but I assume that if a cell is `NULL`,
`getString()` might return `NULL` as well. In SQL `NULL` and empty string are
not the same. For this reason, if `getString()` returns `NULL`, this is valid
value for the results. I reflect that in the print loops, where I explicitly
check if the cell is `NULL`.

On the other hand if `getString()` doesn't returns `NULL`, I do a copy of it using
`strdup` and if this copy fails, then I evalute that as an error and free the
whole thing and return `NULL`. Like I said, I don't know the C interface of
MySQL. A quick search of this method showed me C++ answers only and it returns a
`std::string`. If that's the case, you should use `strdup(res.c_str())`. But
this is speculation of my side, because I don't know the MySQL C interface.

If your system does not have `strdup`, you can write your own:

```
char *strdup(const char *text)
{
    if(text == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *dup = calloc(strlen(text) + 1, 1);

    if(dup == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return strcpy(dup, text);
}
```

But to be honest, if the MySQL interface you are using is a C++ one, you should
not want to use the C way, using `std::vector` would be much easiert and cleaner
C++ implementation. I give you the C answer because you asked for a C answer.